# Displaying content on user profile where both profile and content contains the same vocabulary term

Tags: drupal-7, view, taxonomy

I have vocabulary ("Country") and content type with a field (called "News") linked to this vocabulary which is display as list of terms. Also I created  user profile with the same taxonomy field.
Then I created news with country value set to "Poland" and i want to display news with this value only to users who selected "Poland" in their profiles.

I use Profile2 for create user's profiles.

My question is: How should I configure views to display news?